# DJANGO upload images dont show the django form

Tags: python, html, django, python-2.7, django-forms

I have a simple auth app in Django and now I want the authentication users to can upload easy multiple files from page on website.

i have create a multiupload Django form and views and html form i am not sure if my code is perfect first time play with auth but not work anyway.

in the html page don't show me the form for upload show only the submit button and do nothing that.

[button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Behfq.jpg)

model.py

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    upload = models.ImageField(upload_to='upload')
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def upload_images(request):
    uploadimages = UploadImagesForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if uploadimages.is_valid():
        # Get the images that have been browsed
        if request.FILES.get('multipleimages', None):
            images = request.FILES.getlist('multipleimages')
            for image in images:
                MyModel.objects.create(user=request.user.id, images=image)
        else:
            pass
    else:
        raise Http404
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'UploadImagesForm':UploadImagesForm })
```

forms.py

```
class UploadImagesForm(forms.Form):
    multipleimages = forms.ImageField(label="Upload Multiple Images:",widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}), required=False)
```

html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container">
<div class="row">

<div class="jumbotron">
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <p><form class="" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}


              {{ UploadImagesForm }}

            <input type="submit" name="" value="Submit">

          </form></p>
  <img src="static/css/me.jpg" width="777px" height="555px";alt="some image"/>
</div>
</div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are raising a 404 page when the image is not valid. That's not very user excperience friendly!

Change to this:

```
@login_required
def upload_images(request):
    uploadimages = UploadImagesForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if uploadimages.is_valid():
        # Get the images that have been browsed
        if request.FILES.get('multipleimages', None) is not None:
            images = request.FILES.getlist('multipleimages')
            for image in images:
                MyModel.objects.create(user=request.user, upload=image)
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'UploadImagesForm':UploadImagesForm })
```

Comment: That's strange. I tested it locally and works pretty well. Try to put `{{ UploadImagesForm }}` outside of the `{% block content %}` to see if it gets rendered.

Comment: yes thnx you are correct now show me the forma but not work I have this `error IntegrityError at /
UNIQUE constraint failed: log_mymodel.user_id` is wrong id in view ?

Comment: That's because there is violation of the `unique=True`. You're passing the same user, so your database complains!

Comment: how to fix ?unique=False ?that is wrong I thing ?tell me your proposal

Comment: Since a user may have multiple photos, then yes, your should remove the `unique=True` entirely (the default is `False`).

Comment: I will test now